# Average of Even Numbers and Product of all Odd Numbers

Tags: c, integer, average, product

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int getn(int n, int i);

int main()
{
    int n, i;

    getn(n, i);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
int getn(int n, int i)
{
    int even = 0;
    int odd = 1;
    int avg;

    printf("Enter ten integers: \n");
    for (i = 1 ; i <= 10 ; i++)
    {
        printf("Integer %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &n);
        if ( n % 2 == 0 )
        {
            even = even + n;
        }
        else
        {
            odd = odd * n;
        }
    }
    avg = even / 10;
    printf("\n\nAverage of even numbers: %d", avg);
    printf("\nProduct of odd numbers: %d", odd);
}
```

It seems the even calculations worked but when it comes to odd it gives the wrong answer. Please help
Our instructor wants us to use looping or iterations. No arrays. Please help me

Comment: Formatting and indentation is not important for the compiler, but it is important for humans trying to read your code. Please edit your question to make it more readable.

Comment: What if avg's result is a decimal? int -> float, think of that

Comment: Why are you passing `n` and `i` to `getn`?  They're just being used as local variables in `getn`, and they're undefined in `main`.

Comment: Make sure the product of your numbers fit an int. Or try using long or float

Comment: What did you get, vs what did you expect ? https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: I see no fault in the results - except (as mentioned by joemartin94) float for average. Also, what if no odd numbers are entered at all - their product would not be 1, as your intial value would remain. Need a counter and fix to 0 for odd if that counter is still 0 after your loop. Also shorter code even += n and odd *= n ;-)

Comment: *"it gives the wrong answer"* Not good enough. Read [mcve], and then [edit] and give input, output and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

First, your C code needs some correction:

1. at least give the prototype of `getn` before using it
2. `getn` is defined to return an `int` and doesn't return anything. Either replace `int` with `void` or return a value.

Second,

1. Your code computes the product of ten numbers, if this product is too big, it cannot be store as-is in an `int`. For example, it works well if you enter ten times number 3, the result is 59049, but if you enter ten times number 23, it will answer 1551643729 which is wrong because 23^10=41426511213649 but that can't be stored in an `int`. This is known as *arithmetic overflow*.
2. Your average is bad, because you sum `int`s, but the average is (in general) a rational number (average(2,3)=2.5 isn't it ?). So `double avg = out/10.0;` (means compute a floating division) and `printf("Average %f\n",avg);` would be better.